# Unity WWW Class Method Post has errors on IIS7.5 with Coldfusion 9 on file upload

Tags: http, coldfusion, unity-game-engine, iis-7.5, http-post

Using Unity 4.0

I am trying to use Unity to upload a file to my ColdFusion 9 Webserver on IIS 7.5

IIS Returns error 500 with no explanation....

I Turned on IIS Failed Request Tracing Rules. This let me see the Headers being sent to the server from Unity

```
Content-Length: 496473
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="ZlJady3vWV8N5mlsvGGGJ3MEbxdsDabqkUtreBBK"
Accept: */*
Expect: 100-continue
Host: www.test.com
User-Agent: UnityPlayer/4.3.0f4 (http://unity3d.com)
```

This is in the section General Request Entity

```
--ZlJady3vWV8N5mlsvGGGJ3MEbxdsDabqkUtreBBK
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-disposition: form-data; name="frameCount"

35805
--ZlJady3vWV8N5mlsvGGGJ3MEbxdsDabqkUtreBBK
Content-Type: image/png
Content-disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file.png"

%89PNG
%1A
```

This all looks fine to me so far....Then I get a bunch of 
GENERAL_REQUEST_ENTITY  lines that contain the file data...
Buffer %16%D9%E6%B0Ck#%E2%84I-/%EB%06%05%FB't that goes on and on

Until the last one...
Buffer 9%97%B7'%BE%D0%AB%09%C9%AD%88%D2

Then it calls the ColdFusion DLL with CALL_ISAPI_EXTENSION 
C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\lib\wsconfig\1\jrun_iis6_wildcard.dll

Then the error:
MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS 
ModuleName IsapiModule 
Notification 128 
HttpStatus 500 
HttpReason Internal Server Error 
HttpSubStatus 0 
ErrorCode 0 
ConfigExceptionInfo
Notification EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER 
ErrorCode The operation completed successfully. (0x0)

So something in ColdFusion is bombing....
A trip through the ColdFusion logs find nothing related to the original request

I tried posting the same thing to an older version of Coldfusion 6.1 and it produced this error:

500 Corrupt form data: no leading boundary:  != --xnwss9NYfDunlkBN78LJhFHrlEDhqxHdKuXJxmjf

Unity seems to generate the proper boundary values to IIS 7.5 that we could see above but I'm not sure....Is there supposed to be an ENDING Boundary that is not being sent?

Unfortunately I can't see the actual data being sent by Unity or received by the server except in the IIS 7.5 failed request log.

I see plenty of posts where people are uploading files to PHP without problems,

Here is my Code:

```
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField("frameCount", Time.frameCount.ToString());
form.AddBinaryData ( "file", Image1.EncodeToPNG());
//Hashtable myheaders = new Hashtable();    
//myheaders.Add("enc-type", "multipart/form-data");
WWW w = new WWW("http://www.test.com/AuctionImages.cfm",form);
```

It's basically just copied from examples that seem to work for other servers...
I played with passing headers for enc-type but WWW is supposed to do that automatically according to the docs.

I tried passing the mime type in the AddBinaryData method

If I axe the AddBinaryData line it posts to the page just fine.

Does anyone know a webpage tool I can set as my post URL that would spit out what it received from the post including headers?

Has anyone had any similar problems with file uploads using Unity WWW Class?

Thank you!
Ryan

Comment: Just confirmed that an ENDING Boundary is required per RFC [link] (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1867) It does NOT look like Unity is sending the trailing Boundary.  Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: You should be able to use something like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to monitor the network traffic.

Comment: Thank you! I got Fiddler and checked the request...What I found was that Unity Adds this header. Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="CaVdLtDsgo1hJXK2mBx9Fexo8uMh50k11a1zgD3m"

Comment: Chrome, IE and Firefox uses this Header: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------305343169213653

Comment: I think it's the QUOTES that Unity puts around the boundary field. Coldfusion must be using the whole string including the quotes as the boundary! Now how to be sure??? I have to figure out a way to make Unity not pass the quotes...like do a replace on the headers before it sends...

Answer (score 0):

Ryan you may have almost solved the problem yourself in that it may be that ColdFusion is incorrectly (Or correctly!) interpreting the multi-part boundary headers.

You can test this by manually forming the headers yourself:

```
var form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField("name","value");
var headers = form.headers;
var rawData = form.data;
var url = "www.myurl.com";

// Add a custom header to the request:
headers["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data";
headers["Boundary"] = "---------------";

// Post a request to an URL
var www = new WWW(url, rawData, headers);
yield www;

//.. process results from WWW request here...
```

More documentation on the form headers [HERE](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWWForm-headers.html).

Comment: Hey thanks for taking the time to answer. I have been spending the whole day on this and found out a bunch of stuff.

Comment: Make sure to update your original post with your updates. Helps future people work it out. :)

Comment: 1st) Fiddler is very  handy. Can't believe I haven't had this in my toolbox. 2) Unity seems to put two cr/lf's after the header where Cold Fusion only wants one. The Quotes thing around the Boundary didn't pan out...ColdFusion doesn't care. Unity sticks a Content Type on each field of the form that ColdFusion doesn't like, it only wants it on the FILE fields. Using Fiddler I can take the Unity request..Fiddle with it...and send it again getting it to work...mostly...but being able to adjust all these things within Unity, it's not looking so good. But I'm still fiddling...Ryan

Comment: You might want to submit a bug report to Unity then, if its a genuine mistake on Unity's part. You'll want to supply a lot of evidence though.

Answer (score 0):

You need enable `http post get protocols.Change Web.config` file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings />
    <connectionStrings />
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true">
        </compilation>
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet" />
        <add name="HttpPost" />
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
        <identity impersonate="false" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".unity3d" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```